# Disable Price Book Lookup

Tags: pricebook

when an opportunity is created and saved, "Choose price book screen appears". I have inherited sales cloud environment where no documentation has been provided, now the business requirement is not to use Price Books.

I have disabled all price books, and all price books are inactive at the moment and yet this screen appears, how should I disable this function? 
Please help - Prashant

[image: Choose Price Book]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I strongly suspect your issue is related to this item from the documentation: [Make It Easy to Add Products to Opportunities](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_oppproduct.htm&type=5):

> Set up Salesforce to prompt your users to add products when they create an opportunity. When you select Prompt users to add products to opportunities in Opportunity Settings, the label for the save button in a new opportunity record is “Save & Add Product.”

Comment: Hi crmprogdev, any inputs on where to look in opportunity settings leading to editing this feature?, I tried looking into opportunity object settings including related fields but not much success